# Security implications of not verifying domain ownership on embeddable website tools like disqus

Tags: web

Context: Disqus and similar tools allow content creators to have an embedded "chat box" so that site visitors can comment on your content.

I noticed recently that when I sign up I can claim ownership of any domain, even if I don't actually own it.

I found that rather concerning, but personally don't know what the risks of this could be.

Does anyone know of any known issues that Disqus et al have had as a consequence of this? Or issues that could occur in the future? I assume they don't do domain validatiion because it creates friction in the sign up process.

Comment: I don't think there's any issue here. If you claim a domain you don't own, you cannot embed the Disqus chat on anything.

Comment: Is it possible to assert ownership of a domain that already has Disqus embedded and take control of the moderator tools? Is it possible to assert ownership of a domain and prevent the true owners from embedding Disqus? On the other hand, are you sure "claiming ownership" is what you're really doing, instead of just an arbitrary URL to put on your profile (similar to what is on Stack Exchange)?